# Why does State disappear only upon variable assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-dom

I've got a very simple setup for a file gallery I'm making, which involves a master component, and two sub-components. The image preview has left and right arrows of course, that are passed, and pass back, a function creatively called "clickHandler" that simply updates the state of which file is being looked at.

However, when calling the clickHandler event, and creating a temporary variable to modify and send back to state, the application crashes on a `_this.state.activeFile is not a function` error.

The strange part of this, however, is that the state is completely readable. It can `console.log()` out perfectly, and only upon attempting to *assign it to a variable to modify* does it error.

Here is the sub-component which passes fine:

```
<FileView 
    file={this.props.media[this.state.activeFile]} 
    handler={this.clickHandler} 
    active={this.state.activeFile} 
    max={this.props.media.length}
/>
```

More Detail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iccBD.png

And here is where the method is being called.

```
state={
    activeFile: 2
}
clickHandler=(direction)=>{
    console.log (this.state); // > Object { activeFile: 2 }
    console.log (this.state.activeFile); // > 2
    let temp =  (this.state.activeFile) //  TypeError: _this.state.activeFile is not a function

    // vvv Likely unrelated, but posted also for context
    // evals left or right to plus or minus
    (direction==="prev"?temp-=1:(direction==="next"?temp+=1:""))
    this.setState({activeFile: temp})
}
```

More Detail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSkOX.png

As you can see, the data is present and readable, but not assignable. I've never seen anything like this, and have tried a myriad of solutions like `this.state["activeFile"]` to no avail.

This one's really throwing me for a loop, I appreciate any help in advance!

*Content-unprofessional Codepen Prototype for demonstration:*

https://codepen.io/Jop/pen/vvJrqv

Comment: You should post code and error messages using the formatting tools available instead of posting images, it helps a lot :)

Comment: you have more code inside `clickHandler()` you have commented as `eval left or. right to plus or minus` you should post that too

Comment: I was not ready for a dabbing Luigi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something with react, it is something with javascript!
The code with the error, you posted like this:

```
let temp =  (this.state.activeFile) //  TypeError: _this.state.activeFile is not a function

// vvv Likely unrelated, but posted also for context
// evals left or right to plus or minus
(direction==="prev"?temp-=1:(direction==="next"?temp+=1:""))
```

But because of the way the syntax works, javascript sees this as

```
let temp = (this.state.activeFile)(direction==="prev"?temp-=1:(direction==="next"?temp+=1:""))
```

And you see how it thinks it expects a function now ;)
If you rewrite it to

```
let temp =  this.state.activeFile;

if (direction === "prev") {
  temp -= 1;
} else if (direction === "next") {
  temp += 1;
}
```

It should work :)

Comment: Oh! That makes a whole lot more sense! I guess it's one of those rare cases where the interpreter isn't able to auto-format correctly because of the ternary. 

Thanks, that really clarifies things - and I'll be a lot more careful when using those in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can review this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
<FileView handler={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Isn't that redundant as the ES6 arrow function is already taking care of it? Also it's already in correct scope, as the console.log() is hitting the same state.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vlvudm
I tried what you want to do here. but no problems

Answer (score 0):

When you want to modify your state based on the preceding value, it is not recommended to use `this.state.[x]` directly into the `setState` function, as it is prone to bug.

The recommended way is to use `this.setState(prevState => ({  }))` and use the variables from `previousState`.

Also, sending `-1` and `1` from your functions makes it WAY easier to process :

MediaViewer :

```
clickHandler = offset => event => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ activeFile: prevState.activeFile + offset }))
}
```

ActiveFile :

```
<div className="info-view_paging">
    {props.active < 1 ? <div></div> : <div className="info_pager" onClick={props.handler(-1)}><button>previous</button></div>}
    <div></div>
    {props.max > props.active ? <div className="info_pager" onClick={props.handler(1)}><button>next</button></div> : <div></div>}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! I guess it must have been a problem with asynchronous state or something, considering how the prevState fixed it.



As far as "next" and "prev" goes, I'm working with a more junior developer, so little things keeping semantic bits like that is a bit easier for them to parse when I hand it off to them, even inside of ternaries.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because the code is interpreted as

```
let temp = (this.state.activeFile)(direction==="prev"?temp-=1:(direction==="next"?temp+=1:""))
```

So add semi-colon before `ternary` function or use `else if` statement .Both should work

```
 clickHandler=(supdawg)=>{
    let temp = (this.state.activeFile);
    (supdawg==="left" ? temp-=1 : (supdawg==="right") ? temp+= 1 : "");
    this.setState({activeFile: temp});
}
```

or

```
clickHandler=(supdawg)=>{
    let temp = (this.state.activeFile)
    if (supdawg === "left") { temp -=1}
    else if (supdawg === "right") { temp+=1}
    else {temp = ""}
    this.setState({activeFile: temp})
}
```